# Script reader in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I am trying to make a simple markup language, and I need my Cocoa app to be able to read it. I would prefer to have that code written in Objective-c, but I am happy to use any other language.

Here is my current problem. I am using this code:

```
for (int character = 1; character < ([script length] - 1); character ++) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [[script substringToIndex:character] substringFromIndex:([[script substringToIndex:character] length] - 2)]);
```

Unfortunately, if I pass the string `[button]` through it, it shows this in the debug console:

```
[
[b
[bu
[but
[butt
[__NSCFConstantString substringWithRange:]: Range or index out of bounds
```

I can sort out the error message, but I need to know how to read the script and recognize certain tags like `[button]`. Can anybody give me a link to something useful on this subject?

Comment: Sorry, but as a word of advice try something simpler. Parsing might not be a simple task if you're having "fencepost" errors.

Comment: That is what I am asking here. What can I do to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to give you examples:

```
NSString *str = @"[Button]";
NSUInteger i, len = [str length];

for (i = 1; i <= len; ++i)
    NSLog(@"%@", [str substringToIndex:i]);

for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    NSLog(@"%c", [str characterAtIndex:i]);
```

Output:

```
[
[B
[Bu
[But
[Butt
[Butto
[Button
[Button]
[
B
u
t
t
o
n
]
```

And a more interesting case:

```
for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%%dc", i+1],
          [str characterAtIndex:i]);
```

Which produces:

```
[
 B
  u
   t
    t
     o
      n
       ]
```

Answer (score 2):

This all depends on how complex your scripting language is intended to be, and how efficient and robust it needs to be.

In general, if you don't need a rich syntax, you might be best using XML or JSON for your syntax, and just applying your own semantics to one of those.

Otherwise, parsing is a fairly large, complex field within programming, and you should study up a bit before you dive in (there are dozens of good references, on the web and in books).  I've written 20 or so "simple" parsers over my decades of experience, and I can attest that it's never as easy as you expect.

Comment: Can you give me a link to some of those web references?

Comment: These are some I have bookmarked, though they may be a bit advanced: http://knuth.luther.edu/~leekent/tutorials/ll1.html, http://www.cs.uky.edu/~lewis/essays/compilers/rec-des.html, http://www.itu.dk/people/kfl/parsernotes.pdf, http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/recursive-descent-parsing.html

Comment: In terms of hardcover books, the trio Alfred V. Aho, Ravi Sethi, and Jeffrey D. Ullman, together and separately, wrote maybe a dozen books on compiler topics.  Any one of those would likely be worthwhile to at least skim through.  Some appear to be available for download on the web.